# upload large file causing Error: "Payload content length greater than maximum allowed: 1048576"

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, serverless

I am just trying to invoke one lambda function from another lambda function, and i am sending a payload into that lambda function. If I paas a payload of size upto 1 mb, then i don't get this error, this error arises when the payload size is greater than 1 mb only.

```
import * as AWS from "aws-sdk";

const lambda = new AWS.Lambda({
  region: "us-east-1",
  endpoint: "http://localhost:3002",
});

const params = {
  FunctionName: "myFunction", // the lambda function we are going to invoke
  InvocationType: "RequestResponse",
  LogType: "Tail",
  Payload: JSON.stringify(data),
 };

const lambdaResult = await lambda.invoke(params).promise();
```

Comment: How did it go? Still unclear why you can't do that?

Answer (score 1):

Lambda invocation has [limits](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/gettingstarted-limits.html) on payload (6MB).

If you want to send larger data then that, you have to save it first, for example to **S3**, and then have second function read it from S3. This way you just send S3 url to the second function, instead of the entire data file.